# Acceptability and use of "to got"

Tags: colloquialisms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Don’t got” — how common is it in American usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/649/dont-got-how-common-is-it-in-american-usage)

Recently, I've started to hear more and more often people use "got" as a present simple form  (obviously originating from I have got -> I've got -> **I got** -> **Do you got?** -> **I don't got**).

Although it is without any doubt absolutely colloquial and not officially accepted as "standard", I'd like to ask you, native speakers of American English, whether it sounds acceptable in a normal conversation (would it be at a similar level as any of the following: I wanna, I gotta, I ain't got... ?), whether it is region based, what the third person of this would be (because of its nonstandard origin, I'd guess it should be **he got/he don't got**), and whether it would be used even in the past (**I didn't got**).

Comment: Are you asking native Britons as well? (The answer's No, by the way)

Comment: To got, or not to got, that is the question.

Comment: Which part of the world do you live in? "Native Americans"? Cheyenne, Sioux, Apache, Choctaw, Arapaho, ...? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States.

Comment: @Blessed Geek. I don't think it unreasonable to suppose that Malis means native speakers of American English.

Comment: @blessed - well, sure, you're right, but I think it's clear that I mean native speakers... American because I've never heard a Brit say anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common grammatical construct in African American Vernacular English (AAVE).

“[T]he *is* of *is supposed to* and the *has* of *has got to* are elided consistently in colloquial speech.”[¹](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~wlabov/Papers/CSAA.html)

Comment: And not just in AAVE, either. Everybody in an Anglophone area has heard an Anglophone kid saying _He gots_. This is the way new verbs are born; very very slowly. _Get/Got_ is a particularly complicated example, because there's chromosome sharing with _be_, _do_, and _have_, the other really common auxiliary verbs.

Comment: Thanks. The point however is that I've heard a lot of "European Americans" say that. (E.g. in poker - You don't got it = I don't believe you have good cards)

Comment: @john - so it's he gots/he doesn't got after all?

Comment: See [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html) for more on _got/gotten_ and their various species.

Comment: @Malis: What do you mean "It's"? And "after all" **what**?

Comment: @john Well, I asked about the third person as well and you mentioned _he gots_ (not _he got_).

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" No, thank you. That said, some children say _he gots_ at some point in their learning. _He don't got it_ is just ordinary lectal regularization of _doesn't_ to _don't_, which is marked as slang; and lectal use of _got_ in it's _have_ sense. E.g, _They got gas for 50 cents lower down the road_. _He got_ is how "He's got" is pronounced, just like _I got_ is how "I've got" is pronounced.